# Simple C# Web Service Works Locally but not on Server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, web-services, web-config, asmx

i have a C# web Service, it is very simple,

i have web reference that uses an external WSDL,

Works locally on company machine but not on a company Server.

i have seen on other posts this might be proxy related, but i have tired a few different edits to the webconfig regarding proxy, but i need help from the experts.

When i press invoke when the webservice is running on the server through the browser i am getting the error "Unable to connect to the remote server".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<string xmlns="http://www.service-now.com/CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables">Unable to connect to the remote server</string>
```

WEB CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
  For more information on how to configure your ASP.NET application, please visit
  http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=169433
  -->
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <sectionGroup name="applicationSettings" type="System.Configuration.ApplicationSettingsGroup, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <section name="InboundServiceNowWeb.Properties.Settings" type="System.Configuration.ClientSettingsSection, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </sectionGroup>
  </configSections>
  <system.web>
    <compilation targetFramework="4.5.2" debug="true"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2"/>
    <customErrors mode="Off"/>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        <add name="HttpPost"/>
      </protocols>
    </webServices>
  </system.web>
  <system.codedom>
    <compilers>
      <compiler language="c#;cs;csharp" extension=".cs" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.CSharpCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:6 /nowarn:1659;1699;1701"/>
      <compiler language="vb;vbs;visualbasic;vbscript" extension=".vb" type="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform.VBCodeProvider, Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35" warningLevel="4" compilerOptions="/langversion:14 /nowarn:41008 /define:_MYTYPE=\&quot;Web\&quot; /optionInfer+"/>
    </compilers>
  </system.codedom>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <bindings/>
    <client/>
  </system.serviceModel>
  <applicationSettings>
    <InboundServiceNowWeb.Properties.Settings>
      <setting name="InboundServiceNowWeb_ServiceNowDev_ServiceNow_CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables" serializeAs="String">
        <value>https://COMPANY.service-now.com/CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables.do?SOAP</value>
      </setting>
    </InboundServiceNowWeb.Properties.Settings>
  </applicationSettings>
  <system.net>
    <defaultProxy enabled="true" useDefaultCredentials="false" />
  </system.net>
</configuration>
<!--ProjectGuid: {55A9796B-1C01-4454-B0C3-942C1C8221B5}-->
```

C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace InboundServiceNowWeb
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Summary description for ServiceNowInboundSOAP
    /// </summary>
    [WebService(Namespace = "http://www.service-now.com/CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables")]
    [WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
    [System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]
    // To allow this Web Service to be called from script, using ASP.NET AJAX, uncomment the following line. 
    // [System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
    public class ServiceNowInboundSOAP : System.Web.Services.WebService
    {

        [WebMethod]
        public string UpdateCatalogRITM(string RITM, string ReturnCode, string ReturnMessage, string Comment)
        {
            // return "Hello World1";
            /*
             //SERVICE REFERENCE-SPECIFIC CODE  
             ServiceNowDev.ServiceNowSoapClient soapClient = new ServiceNowDev.ServiceNowSoapClient();
             soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "sys_ws_catalog";
             soapClient.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "#####";

             ServiceNowDev.update insert = new InboundServiceNowWeb.ServiceNowDev.update();
             //ServiceNowDEV.update response = new ServiceNowDEV.updateResponse();
             ServiceNowDev.updateResponse response = new InboundServiceNowWeb.ServiceNowDev.updateResponse();
             */
            //   WEB REFERENCE-SPECIFIC CODE
            ServiceNowDev.ServiceNow_CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables soapClient = new InboundServiceNowWeb.ServiceNowDev.ServiceNow_CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables();
            System.Net.ICredentials cred = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("sys_ws_catalog", "catalog01");
            soapClient.Credentials = cred;

            ServiceNowDev.update insert = new ServiceNowDev.update();
            ServiceNowDev.updateResponse response = new ServiceNowDev.updateResponse();
            //   END OF WEB REFERENCE CODE */

            insert.RequestNumber = RITM;
            insert.ReturnCode = ReturnCode;
            insert.ReturnMessage = ReturnMessage;
            insert.Comments = Comment;

            try
            {
                response = soapClient.update(insert);
                return response.result;

            }
            catch (Exception error)
            {
                return error.Message;
               // this.Response.Text = error.Message;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "i am getting the error "Unable to connect to the remote server"" - *where* are you getting that error? Do you mean your browser can't connect to it, or can it not connect to something else? Have you had other web applications working on the same server? There's simply too little information for us to go on for the moment...

Comment: Yeah i am getting the error on the Server when i am running it through the browser

Comment: Sorry, that's no clearer. "getting the error on the server" is far from precise. Please *edit your question* to be very, very clear about what you're seeing.

Comment: In your web.config file, if you remove the `?SOAP` from `<value>https://COMPANY.service-now.com/CatalogUpdateAutomationVariables.do?SOAP</value>` do you get a different error ?

Comment: @Subbu yeah i get the same error

Answer (score 0):

After a few tweaks to the company firewall for the servers i was able to connect successfully.

Thanks for your help